# How to create a route for a file in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: jquery, json, laravel, datatable, get

I am Using Datatable in Laravel 5.1 and when load Datatable with jQuery, I do not know how should I add json file for change language?

My code in blade page :

```html
<script>

$(function () {
    dTable = $('#admins').DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "list_admin_ajax",
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "url": "{{ url('/public/include/Persian.json') }}"
        }
    });
    dTable.order( [ 1, 'desc' ] ).draw();
})

</script>
```

But this error was finished:

```
http://localhost:8000/public/include/Persian.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You could clarify your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want set "url" for change language but not found my file

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`asset` helper](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls).

```html
<script>
var language_url = "{{ asset("include/Persian.json") }}";
// ...
</script>
```

Make sure that the file `public/include/Persian.json` actually exists.

Comment: The url parameter should probably be looking like this: `"ajax": "{{ action("Controller@view") }}"`